# Selenium and xpath: finding a div with a class/id and verifying text inside

Tags: java, testing, xpath, selenium

I'm trying to have `xpath` find a `div` and verify that the `div` has a specific `string` of text inside.

Here's the `HTML`:

```
<div class="Caption">
  Model saved
</div>
```

and

```
<div id="alertLabel" class="gwt-HTML sfnStandardLeftMargin sfnStandardRightMargin sfnStandardTopMargin">
  Save to server successful
</div>
```

This is the code I'm using at the moment:

```
viewerHelper_.getWebDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'Caption' and .//text()='Model saved']"));
viewerHelper_.getWebDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='alertLabel'] and .//text()='Save to server successful']"));
```

Specifically:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'Caption' and .//text()='Model saved']
//div[@id='alertLabel'] and .//text()='Save to server successful']
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

To verify this:-

```
<div class="Caption">
  Model saved
</div>
```

Write this -

```
//div[contains(@class, 'Caption') and text()='Model saved']
```

And to verify this:-

```
<div id="alertLabel" class="gwt-HTML sfnStandardLeftMargin sfnStandardRightMargin sfnStandardTopMargin">
  Save to server successful
</div>
```

Write this -

```
//div[@id='alertLabel' and text()='Save to server successful']
```

Comment: Just curious, is there a way to achieve the same objective as above using `findElement(By.className("")`? If so, where would the text to be verfified go? Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

To account for leading and trailing whitespace, you probably want to use `normalize-space()`

```
//div[contains(@class, 'Caption') and normalize-space(.)='Model saved']
```

and

```
//div[@id='alertLabel' and normalize-space(.)='Save to server successful']
```

Note that `//div[contains(@class, 'Caption') and normalize-space(.//text())='Model saved']` also works.

Answer (score 4):

For class and text xpath-

```
//div[contains(@class,'Caption') and (text(),'Model saved')]
```

and

For class and id xpath-

```
//div[contains(@class,'gwt-HTML') and @id="alertLabel"]
```

Comment: First xpath is invalid (checked with FirePath)